# Como obtener la fecha en una consulta sin el formato de hora

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

lo que quiero es que solo me traiga el formato de fecha y sin necesidad que me muestre la hora por ejemplo en el campo periodo para mostrarlo en mi consulta sin necesidad que me muestre la hora ya me esta mostrando la fecha y hora y trato de convertirlo en mi consulta pero no me esta funcionando de la forma que lo realizo

este es mi modelo

```
class importar extends Model
{

    protected $table="fcm_enl_ter_fact";

    protected  $fillable  = [
        'PROVEEDOR','DESC_ENLACE','NO_FACTURA','ID_ENLACE','VALOR_PAGO','PERIODO','FECHA_FACTURA','FECHA_INGRESO','MONEDA','TC_FACTURA'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;
}
```

este es mi controlador

```
class vista extends Controller
{
    public function vista_inicio()
    {

        $datos = importar::select('proveedor','id_enlace','periodo','fecha_factura','fecha_ingreso')->get();

        return \View::make('formulario')->with(
            [
            'datos' => $datos
        ]
        );
    }
}
```

y aqui lo muestro en mi vista y quiero mostrar solo la fecha

```
<div class="content">
                        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>PROVEEDOR</th>
                                <th>ID_ENLACE</th>
                                <th>PERIODO</th>
                                <th>FECHA_FACTURA</th>
                                <th>FECHA_INGRESO</th>

                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($datos as $datos)

                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$datos->proveedor}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$datos->id_enlace}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$datos->periodo}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$datos->fecha_factura}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$datos->fecha_ingreso}}</td>

                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Tienes esos atributos en el array `protected $dates = ['periodo', ...];` de tu modelo?

Comment: ahi coloque mi modelo pero creo que el problema es en la consulta ahi debo convertir me imagino el campo

Comment: Con Eloquent puedes hacerlo más simple, si el tipo de dato en BD es `DATETIME`, puedes agregar esos atributos a `protected $dates = ['periodo'];` en el modelo, y eloquent te devolverá (y tambiéN podrás pasarle al insertar) un objeto Carbon. Luego en la vista lo formateas como quieras, por ejemplo `$datos->periodo-format('Y-m-d')` o `$datos->periodo-format('d/m/Y')`

Comment: Recién veo la etiqueta de oracle, entonces no tendrás una columna `DATETIME` sino `DATE`, lo demás todo igual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EN la vista formatea los campos que tienen que ver con fecha con carbon

```
<div class="content">
                        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>PROVEEDOR</th>
                                <th>ID_ENLACE</th>
                                <th>PERIODO</th>
                                <th>FECHA_FACTURA</th>
                                <th>FECHA_INGRESO</th>

                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($datos as $datos)

                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$datos->proveedor}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$datos->id_enlace}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datos->periodo)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datos->fecha_factura)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datos->fecha_ingreso)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>

                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Te mostrara solo dia-mes-año

Comment: muchas gracias esto resolvio mi problema

Comment: He probado sin la clase y no encuentra la funcion

Answer (score 0):

Debes darle el formato que necesitas a tu campo `DateTime`, por ejemplo:

```
 $date = new DateTime(); // 2020-02-19 11:58:41.564592 America/Bogota (-05:00)
 $format = $date->format('Y-m-d');  // 2020-02-19
```

Comment: Si pero en mi consulta en el codigo como lo realizaria eso es lo que no se como adaptarlo a mi consulta

Answer (score 0):

La biblioteca Carbon posee un método que ayuda a tomar un formato datetime y posterior generar una salida solo con la fecha.

De esta forma lo puedes lograr

```
$datos->fecha_factura->toDateString();
```

Obteniendo en la salida: año mes día

Answer (score 0):

Si dicho campo SIEMPRE va a mostrar únicamente la fecha, entonces deberías aplicar el formato desde el modelo, haciendo el *casting* respectivo:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'fecha_factura' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    'fecha_ingreso' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```